# What is the format req'd for file paths in the terminal s.t. CMD + mouse click opens the file?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, finder, text-editor

I have configured this in the past, and sometimes it works...or not with various linting tool printouts.  For example, some file output might be:

```
foobar/thisorthat/thing.py:123
```

And if it prints out on the command line, a [CMD] + [MOUSE_CLICK] will open that file as if it is a hyperlink in the configured text editor default for that filetype.

Other times, the OS will interpret the string as a hyperlink and try to open it in the browser window (this is not the goal).

My question amounts to: how would I modify the output string:

```
# full question
foobar/thisorthat/thing.py:123

# simplification that still gets it done
foobar/thisorthat/thing.py
```

So that the [CMD]+[MOUSE_CLICK] mechanic opens the file with the text editor rather than the browser?

Comment: The “required format for file paths”?  They are either POSIX or [alias delimited](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ReferenceFilesandFolders.html). What angle are you trying to approach this from?  I’m guessing Applescript/Automator service?  Can you [edit] with some clarifications  and how you approached this?  Please help us by narrowing and focusing this question.

Comment: @Allan I am CMD-Clicking plaintext terminal output in `iterm2`'s terminal

Comment: @Allan the reason I ask is this worked last year, so I figure it can be configured to open strings as files rather than only as urls when CMD-Clicking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Define this Semantic History; found in iTerm's Profiles .

In the Profile editor, under *Advanced → Semantic History*, you can select the application that launches when you select and <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> Click.  Since this is profile specific, you can define different <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> Click actions for each separate profile:  VS Code for Work, Atom for Home, BBEdit for Linux, etc.

[image: iTerm2 Semantic History]

Just choose your action (*Open with Editor*) and select the editor you wish to use and it will open the file as expected.

Comment: great! thanks. got it worked out -- although I am not sure how to un-gray the options in the editor section, I configured it to open with the default application.

Comment: I believe you have to install them.  Mine just show up automatically.

Comment: ah, I have many installed but none are un-grayed.  I installed them via Jetbrains' toolkit, so that might be the issue.

Comment: Possibly.  Try installing another (and remove if so needed) just to see if it gets populated.

Comment: reinstalled `clion`; installed `vscode` as well -- no luck.  I'll try reinstalling vscode via terminal

Comment: That might be good (new) question to ask!